# 64 bit division in ARM Assembly SOS

Tags: assembly, arm, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, division

I am calculating the average of sixteen 64 bit numbers added together and I think that I have done all the addition correctly, but now I need to figure out how to divide a 64 bit number by 16 and I am stuck! Any help would be great thank you so much. Here is my code so far.

```
tableSize       EQU     16
sum             EQU     0x40000000
average         EQU     0x40000008
                MOV r8, #14

                ADR r0, table
                LDR r9, =sum
                LDR r10,=average

                LDR r1, [r0], #1    ;hi #1
                LDR r2, [r0], #1    ;lo #1
SUM
                SUB r8, r8, #1
                LDR r3, [r0], #1    ;hi #2
                LDR r4, [r0], #1    ;lo #2
                ADDS    r5, r2, r4  ;lo 1 + lo 2 set flags
                ADC r6, r1, r3  ;hi 1 + hi 2 + carry
                MOV r1, r6
                MOV r2, r5
                CMP r8, 0   
                BNE SUM

                STR r1, [r9], #8
                STR r2, [r9]
 average
                ;stuck here 


table           DCQ     0x0200200AD00236DD
                DCQ     0x00003401AAC4D097
                DCQ     0x000001102ACFF200
                DCQ     0x00010AA0AD3C66DF
                DCQ     0x0000FC3D76400CCB
                DCQ     0x000090045ACDD097
                DCQ     0x00000FF000004551
                DCQ     0x00000000003C66DF
                DCQ     0x1000200AD00236DD
                DCQ     0x00003401AAC4D097
                DCQ     0x000001102ACFF200
                DCQ     0x00010AA0AD3C66DF
                DCQ     0x1000FC3D76400CCB
                DCQ     0x000090045ACDD097
                DCQ     0x00000FF000004551
                DCQ     0x00000000003C66DF
```

Comment: I know that I need to shift the hi 32 bits and then save the lo bit of that and use logical instructions to move that number into the hi bit of the last 32 bits...I just don't know how to go about doing that...not sure if that helps anyone out

Comment: How are you handling overflow of the 64bit addition?  What happens if I add the eight bit values `128+129`?  Are the 64bits signed or unsigned?  What does the 'C' operations `(i>>4)` do?  Are these things equal; `(a/2 + b/2) == (a+b)/2`?  What must we do to make them equal?  Good news, your ARM code is fine.  You need to think about the math first.

Comment: i changed up my code a little bit because the math was actually not right because of how i structured the loop. I am assuming that the 64 bits are unsigned in this case. also i changed the i>>4 to i>>1 because i am trying to get to the next location in memory...is that correct or do i not even need to post index? also i believe that overflow is taken care of when the carry flag is set and added to the high bit...if the final result is greater than 64 bits i am ignoring the overflow @artlessnoise

Comment: The post increment values should be #4, not #1. Also you can move the sub r8,r8,#1 to the end of the loop and use subs r8,r8,#1 to set Z if the loop is done.

Comment: Before dividing by 16, you may want to add 8 to the 64 bit sum in order to round it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there's a 64 bit signed integer in `r0` and `r1`, one can divide it by 16 with the following instructions:

```
    lsl     r2, r0, #28
    asr     r0, r0, #4
    orr     r1, r2, r1, lsr #4
```

In a nutshell, all we need to do is to shift both halves by four and put lower four bits of `r0` into four upper bits of `r1`.

To get unsigned division, one should use `lsr` instead of `asr`.

In both cases the result will be rounded towards minus infinity. To round the result towards the nearest integer one can add 8 to the integer before division. Also, one can add 15 to round towards plus infinity.